# Kraken API MATLAB client invalid signature error

Tags: matlab, api, cryptography

I'm trying to do some authenticated calls to Kraken private endpoints but without success. I'm still getting an error EAPI:Invalid signature.
Does anybody know what's wrong?

Here's the code:

```
function [response,status]=kraken_authenticated(uri,postdata)

  % test uri='0/private/AddOrder'
  % test postdata='&pair=XBTEUR&type=buy&ordertype=limit&price=345.214&volume=0.65412&leverage=1.5&oflags=post'

  url=['https://api.kraken.com/',uri];
  % nonce
  nonce = num2str(floor((now-datenum('1970', 'yyyy'))*8640000000));
  [key,secret]=key_secret('kraken');
  % 1st hash
  Opt.Method = 'SHA-256';
  Opt.Input  = 'ascii';
  sha256string = DataHash(['nonce=',nonce,postdata],Opt);
  % 2nd hash
  sign = crypto([uri,sha256string], secret, 'HmacSHA512');

  header_1=http_createHeader('API-Key',key);
  header_2=http_createHeader('API-Sign',char(sign));
  header=[header_1 header_2];
  [response,status] = urlread2(url,'POST',['nonce=',nonce,postdata],header);

end
```

Crypto function is in another file:

```
function signStr = crypto(str, key, algorithm)

  import java.net.*;
  import javax.crypto.*;
  import javax.crypto.spec.*;
  import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*

  keyStr = java.lang.String(key);
  key = SecretKeySpec(keyStr.getBytes('UTF-8'), algorithm);
  mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
  mac.init(key);
  toSignStr = java.lang.String(str);
  signStr = java.lang.String(Hex.encodeHex( mac.doFinal( toSignStr.getBytes('UTF-8'))));

end
```

I've also tried

```
sign = crypto([uri,sha256string], base64decode(secret), 'HmacSHA512');
```

but without success.

This is guide for authenticated call HTTPS Header:

```
API-Key = API key
API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key
```

This is guide for authenticated call POST Data:

```
nonce = always increasing unsigned 64 bit integer
otp = two-factor password (if two-factor enabled, otherwise not required)
```

I've tried to pass "nonce" parameter or all parameters in "postdata" to POST data but without success.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in function crypto here:

```
keyStr = java.lang.String(key);
key = SecretKeySpec(keyStr.getBytes('UTF-8'), algorithm);
```

As the base64 encoded private key from kraken is not necessarily UTF-8 encoded, you cannot use UTF-8 encoding to extract the key and pass UTF-8 string to the SecretKeySpec function. You need to use byte array instead.

Similar issues

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5113
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3121

Solution for javascript

github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's the problem. I'm not so familiar with java crypto methods so I overlooked it.
Anyway if anybody is gonna to work with Kraken API via Matlab, another solution is just to use ready made python API client ie. https://github.com/veox/python2-krakenex.

Comment: Hi - how exactly did you connect the python solution with matlab (how exactly do interact with it?) Are there maybe any alternative ideas on how to solve the byte-array problem within matlab to get the above proposal working? Thanks!

Comment: You should look how matlab and python integrates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896899/calling-python-from-matlab